# Getting Connection Strings from App.Config

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-5

In .Net Framework 4.7.2 I use:

```
Public Shared Connection As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Project.My.MySettings.ConnString").ConnectionString)
```

To get my connection string.

However, now I'm using .Net 5.0 and it's throwing me the following two errors:

**ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize**

**ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.diagnostics.**

My App.Config was Auto generated and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Project.My.MySettings.ConnString" connectionString="server=0.0.0.0;userid=rice;password=password;database=db;" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
            <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="FileLog"/>
                    <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                    <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="FileLog"
                 type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                 initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
            <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-5.0 there is a specific section on migrating resources and settings

Comment: @Hursey Thank you! but I'm not trying to migrate I'm just starting a new project on .net5 and only used the .net framework example as it was how I used to do it.

Comment: In that case, think you're going to find the tooling around settings isn't quite the same and likely will have to update you processes.   I've used a few different tools, but honestly nothing I've been overly happy with or match the simplicity of the old project settings

Comment: @Hursey yeah seems that way. Even opening and closing forms is giving me trouble haha

Comment: The very start of this is wrong. Connections need to be disposed. Do not declare a connection as a Class level variable. Declare and dispose with `Using...End Using` blocks in the method where they are used. You may declare your connection string as a class level variable.